# SQL query to exclude records that are part of a group

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, exists

I can't believe this hasn't been answered elsewhere, but I don't seem to know the right words to convey what I'm trying to do. I'm using Ruby/Rails and PostgreSQL.

I have a bunch of Users in the DB that I'm trying to add to a Group based on a name search. I need to return Users that do not belong to a particular Group, but there is a join table as well (UserGroups, with the appropriate FKs).

Is there a simple way to use this configuration to perform this query without having to result to grabbing all the Users from which belong to the group and doing something like `.where.not(id: users_in_group.pluck(:id))` (these groups can be pretty huge, so I don't want to send that query to the DB on a text search as the user types).

Answer (score 0):

> I need to return Users that do not belong to a particular Group

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   users u
WHERE  username ~ 'some pattern'  -- ?
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM user_groups ug
   WHERE  ug.group_id = 123       -- your group_id to exclude here
   AND    ug.user_id  = u.id 
   );
```

See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)